# What does this set mean: $ \{ g \mid g : \{0,1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \} $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have an excercise and there is the set $ \{ g\mid g : \{0,1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \} $. Now I wanted to know, that this set mean? What's the content of it? I know normal sets very well but in my oppinion this has to be a set of functions and I have no idea how it would look like...

Thanks

Comment: What if I told you the Cartesian product can be represented as a space of function from some indexing set to the values at each index?

Comment: So in this case you mean, that this is equal to $\mathbb{N}^2$? Could you maybe provide further lecture/sources for this, which explain it a bit more indepth?

Comment: Murkres Topology cover this in Chapter 1 and you can find some information here on the wikipedia page for cartesian products in their full generality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_Cartesian_products

Answer (score 0):

It's the set the functions which have domain $\{0,1\}$ and image a subset of $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the set consists of these functions $g$ such that $g : \{0,1\} \to \mathbb N$. This means that the function $g$ is defined over $\{0,1\}$ and thus its domain is the discrete points $0$ and $1$ and sends them to $\mathbb N$, thus its image is $\mathbb N$ or a subset of $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

It's the set of functions that have a domain of $\{0,1\}$ and a codomain of $\Bbb N$. In other words, each $g$ is a function which sends $0$ and $1$ to a natural number and all such functions are in the set.

Answer (score 0):

$g$ is a function which maps elements of the set $\{0,1\}$ to natural numbers.  And this is the set of all such functions $g$

But, you could think of it as a set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ with $x$ telling you where the function $g$ will map $0,$ and $y$ telling you where $g$ will map $1.$

Answer (score 0):

I think of this set of functions as $\mathbb{N}^2$ because each function will give us a pair $(x_0,x_1)$ given by $(f(0),f(1))$ which will be natural numbers. In fact if I have some indexing set $I$ and some other set $X$ then I can define the Cartesian product of a set with itself as $\prod_{i \in I}X = \{g|g:I \rightarrow X\}$ which can be generalized with a little work.

Comment: Does that mean that the function is equal to $\mathbb{N}^2$?

Comment: This is wrong, the set of discrete elements $\{0,1\}$ is a subet of $\mathbb R$ and has nothing to do with a pair generatir cartesian product.

Comment: oh I mean that the set $\{g|g:\{0,1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}\}$ is equal to $\mathbb{N}^2$?

Comment: @tmpUser12345 No, each function is a point in $\mathbb{N}^2$. For example if we have $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=2$ we can identify that with the point $(1,2)$ and we could call it the $0$ and $1$ coordinate instead of the $x$ and $y$ coordinate. The function is uniquely defined by these two values so the map is a bijection between the points an the functions.

Comment: @Rebellos The set $\{0,1\}$ has no additional structure unless we give it some. Assuming it's a subset of the reals is arbitrary and unmotivated here.